# How to check if only chosen characters are in a string?

Tags: java, string, character

What's the best and easiest way to check if a string only contains the following characters:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_
```

I want like an example like this pseudo-code:

```
//If String contains other characters
else
//if string contains only those letters
```

Please and thanks :)

Comment: Why does everyone suggest regexes? That's slow!

Comment: @thejh: What does your profiler say?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
if (string.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$")) {
  // contains only listed chars
} else {
  // contains other chars
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit verbose compared to a \w and since you are matching the ^ and $ are not needed? Also, your regex looks like it will match an empty string (use of * char). No saying you answer is wrong, just maybe an FYI for the asker.

Comment: Except one case: blank string doesn't contain listed chars, so it should be `+` instead of `*` in pattern.

Comment: Andrew: I wasn't sure if \w(ord) character class matched ONLY with that set of chars

Comment: Andrew: ^ & $ are needed to ensure the String contain ONLY the enumerated chars

Comment: ^ & $ is not needed http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29  and http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

For that particular class of String use the regular expression "\w+".

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
Matcher m = Pattern.matcher(str);

if(m.matches()) {} 
else {};
```

Note that I use the Pattern object to compile the regex *once* so that it never has to be compiled again which may be nice if you are doing this check in a-lot or in a loop. As per the java docs...

> If a pattern is to be used multiple
>   times, compiling it once and reusing
>   it will be more efficient than
>   invoking this method each time.

Comment: nice one! Just one tip: if this needs to be run often the I would make `p` static final.

Comment: Pattern won't work like that.  You would need something like 
    Matcher m = p.matcher( s );
    if ( m.matches()){}
    else{};

Comment: in my non-scientific test, this was by far the fastest, and I used the pattern in Pablo's answer instead of \\w+

Comment: Sorry, fixed my code. though the regex \\w+ is identical to [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ but that's a minor point.

Answer (score 1):

My turn:

```
static final Pattern bad = Pattern.compile("\\W|^$");
//...
if (bad.matcher(suspect).find()) {
  // String contains other characters
} else {
  // string contains only those letters
}
```

Above searches for single not matching or empty string.

And according to JavaDoc for [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
\w  A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]
\W  A non-word character: [^\w]
```